# Determine when a PostgreSQL database was last changed

Tags: backup, postgresql

I'm looking at altering how backups are done and am wondering if there is a way to determine which databases in a postgreql cluster have not been recently changed?

Instead of using pg_dumpall, I'd like to use pg_dump and only dump those databases that have changed since the last backup (some databases don't get updated very often)-- the idea being that if nothing has changed then the current backup should still be good.

Does anyone know of a way to determine when a specific database was last updated/changed?

Thanks...

**Update:**

I was hoping to not have to write triggers all over tha place as I have no control over 
the creation of databases in one particular cluster (let alone creation of db objects within a database).

Digging further, it looks like there is a correlation between the contents of the $PGDATA/global/pg_database file (specifically the second field) and the directory names under $PGDATA/base.

Going out on a limb, I'd guess that the second field of the pg_database file is the database oid and that each database has its own subdirectory under $PGDATA/base (with the oid for the subdirectory name). Is that correct? If so, is it reasonable to use the file timestamps from the files under $PGDATA/base/* as the trigger for needing a backup?

...or is there a better way?

Thanks again...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/899203/how-do-i-find-the-last-time-that-a-postgresql-database-has-been-updated

Comment: Never assume that the current backup is good. You always want to take new backups on your regular schedule.

Comment: Sonu Singh - I can't control the addition of databases, let alone tables to this cluster so triggers won't work-- plus (to my knowledge) triggers won't catch ddl changes.

mrdenny♦ - Correct. However, I'd like to avoid generating redundant incremental backups between the periodic full backups.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While using `select datname, xact_commit from pg_stat_database;` as suggested by @Jack Douglas doesn't quite work (apparently due to autovacuum), `select datname, tup_inserted, tup_updated, tup_deleted from pg_stat_database` does appear to work. Both DML and DDL changes will change the values of tup_* columns while a `vacuum` does not (`vacuum analyze` on the other hand...).

In the off chance that this may be useful for others, I'm including the backup script that I've put in place. This works for Pg 8.4.x but not for 8.2.x-- YMMV depending on the version of Pg used.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
=head1 Synopsis

pg_backup -- selectively backup a postgresql database cluster

=head1 Description

Perform backups (pg_dump*) of postgresql databases in a cluster on an
as needed basis.

For some database clusters, there may be databases that are:

 a. rarely updated/changed and therefore shouldn't require dumping as 
    often as those databases that are frequently changed/updated.

 b. are large enough that dumping them without need is undesirable.

The global data is always dumped without regard to whether any 
individual databses need backing up or not.

=head1 Usage

pg_backup [OPTION]...

General options:

  -F, --format=c|t|p    output file format for data dumps 
                          (custom, tar, plain text) (default is custom)
  -a, --all             backup (pg_dump) all databases in the cluster 
                          (default is to only pg_dump databases that have
                          changed since the last backup)
  --backup-dir          directory to place backup files in 
                          (default is ./backups)
  -v, --verbose         verbose mode
  --help                show this help, then exit

Connection options:

  -h, --host=HOSTNAME   database server host or socket directory
  -p, --port=PORT       database server port number
  -U, --username=NAME   connect as specified database user
  -d, --database=NAME   connect to database name for global data

=head1 Notes

This utility has been developed against PostgreSQL version 8.4.x. Older 
versions of PostgreSQL may not work.

`vacuum` does not appear to trigger a backup unless there is actually 
something to vacuum whereas `vacuum analyze` appears to always trigger a 
backup.

=head1 Copyright and License

Copyright (C) 2011 by Gregory Siems

This library is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it 
under the same terms as PostgreSQL itself, either PostgreSQL version 
8.4 or, at your option, any later version of PostgreSQL you may have 
available.

=cut

use strict;
use warnings;
use Getopt::Long;
use Data::Dumper;
use POSIX qw(strftime);

my %opts = get_options();

my $connect_options = '';
$connect_options .= "--$_=$opts{$_} " for (qw(username host port));

my $shared_dump_args = ($opts{verbose})
    ? $connect_options . ' --verbose '
    : $connect_options;

my $backup_prefix = (exists $opts{host} && $opts{host} ne 'localhost')
    ? $opts{backup_dir} . '/' . $opts{host} . '-'
    : $opts{backup_dir} . '/';

do_main();


########################################################################
sub do_main {
    backup_globals();

    my $last_stats_file = $backup_prefix . 'last_stats';

    # get the previous pg_stat_database data
    my %last_stats;
    if ( -f $last_stats_file) {
        %last_stats = parse_stats (split "\n", slurp_file ($last_stats_file));
    }

    # get the current pg_stat_database data
    my $cmd = 'psql ' . $connect_options;
    $cmd .= " $opts{database} " if (exists $opts{database});
    $cmd .= "-Atc \"
        select date_trunc('minute', now()), datid, datname, 
            xact_commit, tup_inserted, tup_updated, tup_deleted 
        from pg_stat_database 
        where datname not in ('template0','template1','postgres'); \"";
    $cmd =~ s/\ns+/ /g;
    my @stats = `$cmd`;
    my %curr_stats = parse_stats (@stats);

    # do a backup if needed
    foreach my $datname (sort keys %curr_stats) {
        my $needs_backup = 0;
        if ($opts{all}) {
            $needs_backup = 1;
        }
        elsif ( ! exists $last_stats{$datname} ) {
            $needs_backup = 1;
            warn "no last stats for $datname\n" if ($opts{debug});
        }
        else {
            for (qw (tup_inserted tup_updated tup_deleted)) {
                if ($last_stats{$datname}{$_} != $curr_stats{$datname}{$_}) {
                    $needs_backup = 1;
                    warn "$_ stats do not match for $datname\n" if ($opts{debug});
                }
            }
        }
        if ($needs_backup) {
            backup_db ($datname);
        }
        else {
            chitchat ("Database \"$datname\" does not currently require backing up.");
        }
    }

    # update the pg_stat_database data
    open my $fh, '>', $last_stats_file || die "Could not open $last_stats_file for output. !$\n";
    print $fh @stats;
    close $fh;
}

sub parse_stats {
    my @in = @_;
    my %stats;
    chomp @in;
    foreach my $line (@in) {
        my @ary = split /\|/, $line;
        my $datname = $ary[2];
        next unless ($datname);
        foreach my $key (qw(tmsp datid datname xact_commit tup_inserted tup_updated tup_deleted)) {
            my $val = shift @ary;
            $stats{$datname}{$key} = $val;
        }
    }
    return %stats;
}

sub backup_globals {
    chitchat ("Backing up the global data.");

    my $backup_file = $backup_prefix . 'globals-only.backup.gz';
    my $cmd = 'pg_dumpall --globals-only ' . $shared_dump_args;
    $cmd .= " --database=$opts{database} " if (exists $opts{database});

    do_dump ($backup_file, "$cmd | gzip");
}

sub backup_db {
    my $database = shift;
    chitchat ("Backing up database \"$database\".");

    my $backup_file = $backup_prefix . $database . '-schema-only.backup.gz';
    do_dump ($backup_file, "pg_dump --schema-only --create --format=plain $shared_dump_args $database | gzip");

    $backup_file = $backup_prefix . $database . '.backup';
    do_dump ($backup_file, "pg_dump --format=". $opts{format} . " $shared_dump_args $database");
}

sub do_dump {
    my ($backup_file, $cmd) = @_;

    my $temp_file = $backup_file . '.new';
    warn "Command is: $cmd > $temp_file" if ($opts{debug});

    chitchat (`$cmd > $temp_file`);
    if ( -f $temp_file ) {
        chitchat (`mv $temp_file $backup_file`);
    }
}

sub chitchat {
    my @ary = @_;
    return unless (@ary);
    chomp @ary;
    my $first   = shift @ary;
    my $now     = strftime "%Y%m%d-%H:%M:%S", localtime;
    print +(join "\n                  ", "$now $first", @ary), "\n";
}

sub get_options {
    Getopt::Long::Configure('bundling');

    my %opts = ();
    GetOptions(
        "a"             => \$opts{all},
        "all"           => \$opts{all},
        "p=s"           => \$opts{port},
        "port=s"        => \$opts{port},
        "U=s"           => \$opts{username},
        "username=s"    => \$opts{username},
        "h=s"           => \$opts{host},
        "host=s"        => \$opts{host},
        "F=s"           => \$opts{format},
        "format=s"      => \$opts{format},
        "d=s"           => \$opts{database},
        "database=s"    => \$opts{database},
        "backup-dir=s"  => \$opts{backup_dir},
        "help"          => \$opts{help},
        "v"             => \$opts{verbose},
        "verbose"       => \$opts{verbose},
        "debug"         => \$opts{debug},
        );

    # Does the user need help?
    if ($opts{help}) {
        show_help();
    }

    $opts{host}         ||= $ENV{PGHOSTADDR} || $ENV{PGHOST}     || 'localhost';
    $opts{port}         ||= $ENV{PGPORT}     || '5432';
    $opts{host}         ||= $ENV{PGHOST}     || 'localhost';
    $opts{username}     ||= $ENV{PGUSER}     || $ENV{USER}       || 'postgres';
    $opts{database}     ||= $ENV{PGDATABASE} || $opts{username};
    $opts{backup_dir}   ||= './backups';

    my %formats = (
        c       => 'custom',
        custom  => 'custom',
        t       => 'tar',
        tar     => 'tar',
        p       => 'plain',
        plain   => 'plain',
    );
    $opts{format} = (defined $opts{format})
        ? $formats{$opts{format}} || 'custom'
        : 'custom';

    warn Dumper \%opts if ($opts{debug});
    return %opts;
}

sub show_help {
    print `perldoc -F $0`;
    exit;
}

sub slurp_file { local (*ARGV, $/); @ARGV = shift; <> }

__END__
```

**Update:** the script has been put on github [here](https://github.com/gsiems/pg_backup_as_needed).

Comment: Quite nice code, thanks for sharing. BTW, it could be github'ed, don't you think so? :-)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you can use [`pg_stat_database`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/monitoring-stats.html#MONITORING-STATS-VIEWS-TABLE) to get a transaction count and check if this changes from one backup run to the next:

```
select datname, xact_commit from pg_stat_database;

  datname  | xact_commit 
-----------+-------------
 template1 |           0
 template0 |           0
 postgres  |      136785
```

If someone has called [`pg_stat_reset`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/interactive/monitoring-stats.html#MONITORING-STATS-FUNCS-TABLE) you can't be certain if a db has changed or not, but you may consider it unlikely enough that that would happen, followed by exactly the right number of transactions to match your last reading.

--EDIT

see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3718676/postgres-statistics-pg-stat-get-db-xact-commit) for why this might not work. Not sure why this might happen but enabling logging might shed some light....

Comment: If someone did call `pg_stat_reset` then the probability of the xact_commit value matching the previous whould be pretty low, no? So that certainly looks to catch the existence of DML changes. Now all I need is to catch if there have been DDL changes.

Comment: DDL is transactional in postgres - I'd expect the commit count to increase in that case too. Not checked though...

Comment: You Sir, are correct. I had forgotten about Pg DDL being transactional and a quick `create table ...` test does appear to increment xact_commit.

Comment: Further testing shows the xact_commit increasing even though there is no user activity going on-- autovacuum perhaps?

Comment: This definitely doesn't work for backup purposes. xact_commit increases very frequently, even when nobody is connected to the database.

Answer (score 1):

From digging around the postgres docs and newsgroups:

[`txid_current()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-TXID-SNAPSHOT) will give you a new `xid` - if you call the function again at a later date, if you get a `xid` one higher, you know that no transactions committed between the two calls. You may get false positives though - eg if someone else calls `txid_current()`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I don't belive this will work however as txid_current() appears to operate at the cluster level rather than the database level.

Comment: I looked for some doc on that and couldn't find - do you have a link?

Comment: No link. I tested by switching between databases and running "select current_database(), txid_current();" and comparing the results.

Answer (score 0):

Rember the time-stamp on your files containing the DB-data and look if they have changed. If they did there was a write.

Edit after WAL-hint: You should do this only after flushing the outstanding writes.

Comment: That's not rely reliable. There could be changes that are not yet written (flushed) to the datafiles, i.e. they were only written to the WAL.

Answer (score 0):

Postgresql 9.5 let us to track last modified timestamp check out this link
https://thirumal-opensource.blogspot.in/2017/03/to-track-last-modified-commit-or-get.html